# How to decode or convert base64 string url to UintList in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this base64Result from `canvas.toDataURL()` but I having difficulties parsing in Dart to 'UintList'

```
  import 'dart:convert';

  final String base64Result = result.toString();
  print("$logTrace calling web function done ${base64Result.length}");
  final bytes = base64Url.decode(base64Result);


character (at character 5)
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARwAAAIrCAYAAAA9YyZoAAAgAElEQ...
    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`'data:image/png;base64,'` is part of the data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), not part of a base-64 string.  You need to extract the base-64 data from the URL first.

Luckily, the [`UriData` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData-class.html) can do this all for you:

```dart
final bytes = UriData.parse(base64Result).contentAsBytes();
```

Comment: Yours is definitely better in terms of readability but which  is better in terms of performance? I diid this
   final bytes = base64Url.decode(base64Result.split(';base64,')[1]);
    return bytes;

Comment: There shouldn't be any perceptible difference in performance. `UriData` internally should be doing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry to bother you agin. Do you know how to do the reverse ? From bytes to Data Url ?

Comment: Use the [`UriData.fromBytes` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData/UriData.fromBytes.html) (e.g. `UriData.fromBytes(bytes).toString()`).